# Is it possible to simplify $3\sin(z)\cos^2(z)-\sin^3(z)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I have to write $\sin(3z)$ only with $\sin$'s and $\cos$'s. By using the additions-theorem I obtained $3\sin(z)\cos^2(z)-\sin^3(z)$ and I don't know If I can continue simplifying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$3 \sin z \cos^2 z - \sin^3 z = \sin z (3 \cos^2 z - \sin^2 z) = \sin z (3(1-\sin^2 z) - \sin^2 z) = \sin z(3 - 4 \sin^2 z) = 3 \sin z - 4 \sin^3 z$

Entirely in terms of $\sin z$, if that counts as a simplification.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: your term simplifies to $$\left( 4\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}-1 \right) \sin
 \left( x \right) 
$$

Comment: This is a simplification?

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what "simplify" means in this context -- very often, two equivalent trigonometric formulas can be equally "simple" -- but one thing you can do is replace $\cos^2(z)$ with $1-\sin^2(z)$.  Then you'll have
$$3\sin(z)(1-\sin^2(z))-\sin^3(z)$$
$$3\sin(z)-3\sin^3(z)-\sin^3(z)$$
$$3\sin(z)-4\sin^3(z)$$